# How to read/write specific data on Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm having some problem with the READ `rules` of Firestore currently

Here is my data structure

```
{
  email: example@gmail.com,
  username: geekGi3L,
  birthday: 1995/02/14,
  photo: <firestore-download-url>
}
```

The `rules` currently I set is

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{user} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == user;
    }
  }
}
```

How could I set the `rules` to allow user to READ the **specific fields** like `email` and `birthday` only if `request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == uid` while `username` and `photo` should be readable by every user?

Thank you <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firstore, there is no per-field access control for reading fields of a document.  The most granular unit of access is the document.  A user either has full access to read a document in its entirety, or they don't have any access at all.

If you need to change access per field, you'll have to split the fields of the document into multiple collections, with each collection having access control appropriate for the fields of the documents within.  It's very common to have a split between public and private data like this.